# this.someFunction is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

After having read about the `bind` requirement for methods to be bound to a React ES6 class, I am still having some difficulty with this example:

```
class ProductList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { products: [] };
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateState();
  }

  handleProductUpvote(productId) {
    Data.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.id === productId) {
        item.votes = item.votes + 1;
        return;
      }
    });
    this.updateState();
  }

  updateState() {
    const products = Data.sort((a,b) => {
      return b.votes - a.votes;
    });
    this.setState({ products });
  }

  render() {
    const products = this.state.products.map((product) => {
      return (
        <Product
          key={'product-' + product.id}
          id={product.id}
          title={product.title}
          description={product.description}
          url={product.url}
          votes={product.votes}
          submitter_avatar_url={product.submitter_avatar_url}
          product_image_url={product.product_image_url}
          onVote={this.handleProductUpvote}
        />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className='ui items'>
        {products}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Product extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleUpvote = this.handleUpvote.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpvote() {
    this.props.onVote(this.props.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='item'>
        <div className='image'>
          <img src={this.props.product_image_url} />
        </div>
        <div className='middle aligned content'>
          <div className='header'>
            <a onClick={this.handleUpvote}>
              <i className='large caret up icon'></i>
            </a>
            {this.props.votes}
          </div>
          <div className='description'>
            <a href={this.props.url}>
              {this.props.title}
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className='extra'>
            <span>Submitted by:</span>
            <img
              className='ui avatar image'
              src={this.props.submitter_avatar_url}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <ProductList />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

This returns

`Uncaught TypeError: this.updateState is not a function(...)` at `handleProductUpvote`

Is the initialized binding not sufficient in this case?

Comment: `onVote` prop on `Product` must have `this` bound to the component or else `this` will be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see this issue, you don't want to be adding the bind to *the method that it's trying to call right then*, but the method that you are inside of when the "this.xxx not defined" issue occurs.

Currently, it's getting the function `handleProductUpvote` just fine - but it's calling it in the wrong object context. So you need to do the same thing as you did with `updateState` in the constructor, but with that function. Though I have limited react knowledge I believe it's common to do that for every function that's used as an event listener or callback.

Comment: That was it. Makes perfect sense. Shoulda caught that.